# KnockoutJs Hyperlink to new Tab

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, kogrid

I have an ASP.Net MVC website that uses KnockoutJS and KOGrid in the views. It dynamically renders hyperlinks in one particular column as follows:

```
cellTemplate: '<a data-bind="text:$parent.entity.sendPort, attr: { href: $parent.entity.sendPortLink}" ></a>'
```

It's been decided that when clicked, the browser should present the new page in a new tab. So, I've tried adding the "target" attribute as follows:

```
cellTemplate: '<a data-bind="text:$parent.entity.sendPort, attr: { href: $parent.entity.sendPortLink, target:"_blank"}" ></a>'
```

This didn't work. The hyperlink was rendered but unable to click.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the double quotes. Double quotes are used for both the `data-bind` attribute and the `target` property. The opening double-quote of the `target` property closes the `data-bind` attribute.

Also there is no need to put the target in the data binding. The data is not dynamic so could simply be added to the `a` element:

Try changing it to:

```
cellTemplate: '<a target="_blank" data-bind="text:$parent.entity.sendPort, attr: { href: $parent.entity.sendPortLink }" ></a>'
```